# Error: wrong number of arguments specified for ‘constructor’ attribute

Tags: c++, linux, constructor, g++

Before the actual implementation, i wrote a small prototype code, and put a class constructor and ctor constructor in the same file, to see if the ctor would execute first, which is my actual implementation.

However, i am facing an error. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void startMe(void) __attribute__ ((constructor(1)));
extern "C" void ending(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));

class Test {

 public:

    Test()
    {
      cout << "This is test constructor" << endl;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
  Test();
  printf("Now main called\n");
 }

 void startMe(void)
 {
  printf("Start me called before main\n");
 }

 void ending(void)
 {
  printf("Destructor called\n");
 }
```

--

```
Output:
 $ g++ constructor1.cc 
 constructor1.cc:10: error: wrong number of arguments specified for ‘constructor’ attribute
```

However, when i remove the constructor priority, it compiles and runs fine. That is, i do:

```
extern "C" void startMe(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
```

Why is it so? How to give priority?

Please help me. My idea is "ctor" should be executed first, then the other (Test) constructor. The same reason, i have put ctor as a priority 1.

Comment: C has no constructors or destructors. Tag removed.

Comment: It has, that is what is ctor. The tag should not be removed. I have rolled it back.

Comment: You can add a constructor to a C code..search my earlier posts..FYI.

Comment: @kingsmasher: "ctor" is the abbrevation of "constructor" and there is no such thing in C, tag removed.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: it also doesn't have `extern "C"` or classes or `<iostream>` or `using` or `namespace` or `cout` or (**very**) strange usage of the operator `<<`, or ... , ... , ....

Comment: That is different, my idea is, my file can be linked with C and C++ code. This is a snippet. __attribute__((constructor)) allows constructors in C language..i think we are swaying away from the actual discussion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work

Comment: Maybe you want to tag your question with `gcc` ... and untag `c`, `c++`, `g++` :)

Comment: The real question is are you compiling the code as C or as C++? Please choose tags that accurately reflect the question, not just those that are closely associated in your mind.

Comment: Both. This question won't make sense for C++ and non-Linux folks because they won't get the ctor concept. This code is actually a snippet of a library, that can be linked with C as well as C++. I am testing with both "as in" C and as in "C++". So many people i repeated the same answer i guess :(

Comment: I do not believe you that you compile this code with a C compiler, as C has no notion of `class`es.

Comment: I've removed the C tag again.  The fact that this can be linked into a C program is completely tangential to the actual question.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 It doesn't matter that that the final product is a library that can be used by C++ programs. Plenty of languages can interface with C and produce a library that can be linked to a C program. It doesn't make sense to use the C tag for those or this question either. Nor does it matter that you are using a GCC extension.

Comment: You're right, I'm not a Linux folks. But I'm still really curious to know what C compiler you're using that understands the keyword `class`. I asked what you're compiling **this** code as, C or C++, not what language you eventually want to try and call it from. You could be calling it from C# or VB or Lua too. I can't see how that's relevant to the question itself.

Comment: @Luc: I agree about C, but AFAICS, the question is specifically about the interaction between the GCC extension and C++, so I think the GCC tag is relevant.

Comment: @Oli It is. I was mentioning that in relation to the C tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling your program as is yields:

```
warning: constructor priorities from 0 to 100 are reserved for the implementation
```

Changing the priority from 1 to 101 gets rid of the warning and the executable produces:

```
 Start me called before main
 This is test constructor
 Now main called
 Destructor called
```

This is using GCC 4.5

Comment: constructor1.cc:10: error: wrong number of arguments specified for ‘constructor’ attribute

Comment: @kingsmasher1 This is using GCC. Both gcc and g++ do the same thing here.

Comment: Although, it executes fine in my ARM target, but in x86 it fails.

Comment: No, you can't compile it using gcc, u have to use g++ compiler here

Comment: @kingsmasher1 `gcc -lstdc++` can work just fine, not that it's relevant to what's at hand.

Comment: You are linking the C++ library using, -lstdc++. Why will you do that, when you can directly invoke g++? I don't feel it is appropriate way to do (Linking C++ library using C compiler). I feel we are diverting from the actual point. Pls help to clarify the actual question if u can.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 For starters you could provide your GCC version. For all we know the priority feature isn't supported for your version.

Comment: Yes, i think, that is the problem: my CentOS GCC version in x86 has 4.1.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 FWIW the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) for 4.1 doesn't document the priority syntax for constructor attributes.

Comment: Luc, thank you. I think that is the root cause. But then how to make sure that my __attribute__ constructor has highest priority if priority can't be set?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I suggest opening a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

> wrong number of arguments specified for ‘constructor’ attribute

It looks like you are using a downlevel version of GCC.

According to the GCC 4.2.1 docs, the following are the relevant [GCC 4.2.1 Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> constructor
>   destructor
>       The constructor
>   attribute causes the function to be called automatically before
>   execution enters `main ()`...

And the relevant [GCC 4.3.0 Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> constructor
>   destructor
>   constructor (priority)
>   destructor (priority)
>       The constructor
>   attribute causes the function to be called automatically before
>   execution enters `main ()`...

The solution is to use GCC 4.3 or above.

I'm currently testing some software on OpenBSD 5.7, and it ships with the GCC 4.2.1 compiler. We also support CentOS 5, and that ships with the GCC 4.1 compiler. Here's what out code looks like:

```c
// INIT_PRIORITY manages initialization of C++ static objects. Under GCC, 
// the library uses init_priority attribute in the range [INIT_PRIORITY,
// INIT_PRIORITY+100]. Under Windows, INIT_PRIORITY enlists
// "#pragma init_seg(lib)". Undefine or set to 0 to disable it.
#define INIT_PRIORITY 250

#ifdef __GNUC__
# define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#endif
#ifdef __clang__
# define CLANG_VERSION (__clang_major__ * 10000 + __clang_minor__ * 100 + __clang_patchlevel__)
#endif
...

#if __GNUC__ && INIT_PRIORITY && ((GCC_VERSION >= 40300) || (CLANG_VERSION >= 20900))
DLL void API DetectX86Features() __attribute__ ((constructor (INIT_PRIORITY + 50)));
DLL bool API CpuId(word32 input, word32 *output);
#elif __GNUC__ && INIT_PRIORITY
DLL void API DetectX86Features() __attribute__ ((constructor));
DLL bool API CpuId(word32 input, word32 *output);
#else
DLL void API DetectX86Features();
DLL bool API CpuId(word32 input, word32 *output);
#endif
```

---

You should probably create an additional class, like `Initialization`, and put `startMe` in the constructor and `ending` in the destructor. Then, create a static instance of the C++ object, like `Initialization init;`.

To avoid the *[static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)*, you should use [`init_priority`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/C---Attributes.html) (also see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371968) and [Clarification of **attribute** init_priority](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00220.html) on the GCC mailing list). `init_priority` has been around since [at least GCC 3.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/C---Attributes.html).